# Rails Precision searching the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have this to find a DB Entry with the key field the same as the ID params. Now, I get this:

```
undefined method `confirmed=' for<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Email:0x007fd5254c33d8>
```

And the code:

```
    key = Email.where(:key => params[:id])
    if key[1] = nil
      @error = true
    else
        key.confirmed = true
      @error = false
    end
```

I was expecting to get a nil if it wasn't in the DB or a Email Object. I was also thinking it could return a hash of Email objects. There should be 0 or 1 DB Entrys. How should I do this correctly? I have no idea what a ActiveRecord::Relation is.

Comment: I suppose your check should be if `if key[1] == nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Email.where` return multiple records. What you actually want to use is `Email.find_by` which will allow you to pass a hash of conditions you want the record to match (like how `Email.where` works), but will return either the first record found, or nil. Your conditional will need to change as a result

Answer (score 0):

You seem to get it completely wrong. Please get acquainted with [ActiveRecord documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

ActiveRecord::Relation represents query results. Yes, you can update records through it, but this way:

```
key.update_all(confirmed: true)
```

which will update confirmed attribute on all records found by the query.

If you want to check whether it has returned at least one record, use:

```
if key.first
  ...
```

To update this one record only:

```
key.first.confirmed = true
key.first.save
```

or:

```
key.update_attribute(:confirmed, true)
```